# Adding new element of array data in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, indexing

I have a Json dynamic data object.

```
[{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"},{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"},{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"}]
```

and I have to put some data.

```
"identifier" : "userid"
```

then, I try to make code like this.

```
Data.push({"identifier" : "userid"});
```

and result was

```
[{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"},{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"},{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"},{"identifier" : "userid"}]
```

but my goal is

```
[{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb","identifier" : "userid"},{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb","identifier" : "userid"},{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb","identifier" : "userid"}]
```

how can I put some data to special index in existing json data?

Comment: [JSON](https://json.org/) is always a string. If you have an array, it's not JSON.

Comment: `for(obj in Data){Data.obj.push()}`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update/add to the existing array objects, you can make a simple *forEach* loop.

Stack snippet

```js
var array = [{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"},{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"},{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"}]

array.forEach(function(item) {
  item["identifier"] = "userid";
})

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce` function to append every element with new key-value pair

```js
var arr = [{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"},{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"},{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"}]

var result = arr.reduce((r,s) => {
  r.push(Object.assign({}, s, {"identifier" : "userid"}));
  return r;
} , []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think map() will by  perfect for this:

```js
var arr = [
{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"},
{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"},
{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"}]

arr.map(function(x){
x.identifier = "userid"
})

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to push to the array element not the array itself:
so you need to loop on this JSONArray and then for each element push the new variables, like :

```
    for(int x-0; x<Data.length; x++){
       Data[x].push({"identifier" : "userid"})
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say, initially your array is **initArray**.
You can do it by **map** or **forEach**
With forEach you will *make changes in initArray*  while with map *you will process initArray*, which will return a new array.

So,

```
initArray.forEach( function (element)

 { 

element["identifier"] = "userId" 

})

var  newArray = initArray.map(

           function (element) {  

               element["identifier"] = "userId"  

                return element 

            })
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Use `Object.keys` to iterate over the existing array data, and assign the new data to each level using `Object.assign`:

```
var Data = [{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"},{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"},{"stock1":"aaaa","stock2":"bbbb"}];

Data = Object.keys(Data).map(function (i) {
    return Object.assign({}, Data[i], {identifier: 1});
});
console.log(Data);
```

Here is some docs to explain the usage of `Object.assign`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign